# How to tell anonymous events with the same arguments apart?

Tags: solidity, events, topics

Because `anonymous` events do not contain the hash of their signature as their first topic, you cannot easily search for them on the blockchain.

However, if the set of the `indexed` arguments of an `anonymous` event is unique in the contract (say, it is the only one that indexes an `uint256`, followed by a `string`), then, deducing when it has been emitted is relatively simple.

But what if there are 2 anonymous events which the same `indexed` arguments? How do you tell them apart once they're emitted?

Comment: You can extract any information from blockchain transactions. It is all public there. It is just matter of difficulty to how to get them.

Comment: How do you check that a log was produced by an anonymous event then?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to differentiate between the two just by comparing the log output. [According to the solidity documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.19/contracts.html#events), it is even possible to fake the signature of an event using an anonymous event.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

contract Event {
    event Log(address indexed sender, string message);
    event FakeLog(bytes32 indexed sig, address indexed sender, string message) anonymous;

    function test() public {
        emit Log(msg.sender, "Hello World!");
        emit FakeLog(Log.selector, msg.sender, "Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Here, `Log` and `FakeLog` would produce identical outputs.

However, this only means that you cannot identify source from the event data alone. You can always run the transactions on a node and see which event is issued.

Comment: Some eventa may only be emitted when certain users/addresses call the functions emitting them, so "executing the transactions yourself" is not always a good alternative... Unless you execute the transactions programatically in a "fork testing" environment via Foundry, I think.

Comment: When I say "executing the transactions yourself"", I mean execute the transaction on an Ethereum node and watch observe the state changes. I have clarified that in my answer.

Comment: Oh, so, that'd involve running (or having access to) a Full Ethereum node. Gotcha!